# error "ps2pdf returned exit code 1"

Tags: errors, eps

I´m trying to compile a doc with an .eps.

I use Winedt 9, and I use LATEX + DVI2PS + PS2PDF

All runs well with LATEX compilation, and with DVI2PS, BUT... when I use PS2PDF I obtain this message:
"ps2pdf returned exit code 1 indicating that some problems might have ocurred during the compilation"

My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}

\begin{document}

This is a test.\\
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{example-image.eps}\\
  \caption{Fact.Region.}\label{regionfact}
\end{figure}
The cuasi-End!\\

\end{document}
```

A months ago I compiled many .tex with .eps files, but now... I can´t compile this example.

Do you know any solution?.

I read any messages, but I have not the solution.

What the console says is:

[image]

Comment: are there no warnings from ps2pdf?

Comment: unrelated but each of those `\\ ` is mis-placed.

Comment: Maybe an outdated GhostScript... Has that been updated lately?

Comment: What version of GhostScript are you using?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edit the original post an attach the console messages.

Comment: @Werner It was the 9.10, but I just updated to 9.15 a few minutes ago.

Comment: @MikaIke thanks sorry I can't help but someone may recognise that errror

Comment: So the problem occurs with 9.10, or with 9.15, or with both?

Comment: @Werner, with both. I uninstalled the 9.10, and now I have installed only the 9.15.

Comment: @MikaIke: If this is related to the image, perhaps re-process the image using [`eps2eps`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/eps2eps1.html)...

Comment: @werner I think about it but using the mwe package, and the example-image.eps I supposse that the problem isn´t there.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after trying and trying.

At start of this questions I had 
Ghostscript 9.10 and MIKTEX updated on late October´2014
and WinEdt9

but, after reading I have found no solution, I try and try and finally I solved the problem in this way:
- updated Ghostscript from 9.10 to 9.15
- Updated all the packages of MIKTEX with the admin update tool.
- Deleting ghostscript 9.15, so now I don´t have any shostscript on my system. I suposse that MIKTEX have one similar thing, as I did read in any message.

and all runs well now.